# ListView increasement and adapter changed dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Friends. I am new android developer and asking question .I have searchd a lot,but didn't get the desired result.So, Here's my problem.

**1. I have a ListView that conations a number of items**

```
  ListView
 _________
    item1
    item2
    item3
   _________
```

**2. When I click onItem click Listener, I get all the values of item conation(ItemDetail.java)**

**3. Now I have two buttons in (ItemDetail.java) buttonNext and buttonPrevious**

so my query when I click buttonNext and buttonPrevious my listview item detail from list should be changed dynamically increment and decrement of position.

Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: Couldn't be sure. Are you trying to change row order? Like item1,item2,item3 and when next clicked the order should be item2,item1,item3. is that right?

Comment: yes i want to change order of row.that contain detail in layout dynamicaly changed if item1 so when click nextbutton so item2 should be display @Zefnus

Comment: Are you navigate from That List Page to another page ? I mean you are click onItemClick and navigate to another page. Now if you get back to the List page with the Press o back Button at that time the list Should be get changed? right ???

Answer (score 1):

You have to code on onResume of that List Activity.

Just update your adapter with the newly sorted data as you want and refresh the listview with that new data.

In case of any query, let me know.

Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

1. `OnClick()` change collection elements order of the list you used in adapter (list that is binded). `SwapElements(list, index1, index2)`
2. you need to use `runOnUiThread()` to bind data of UI components.

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { refreshListview() } });`

1. `refreshListview()` method is the one you are using for your refresh routine.